# Representation of a power of a quadratic form

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, polynomials, sums-of-squares

Let $A=A^t$ be a non-singular symmetric matrix.  For any multi-index $\gamma=(\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_n)$ of degree $\vert \gamma\vert=\gamma_1+\dots+\gamma_n=2d$, let $b_\gamma=\frac{\partial}{\partial y^\gamma} (y^{\,t} A^{-1} y)^d$. Now, let us order (in any fixed way) the set $\{\alpha,\beta,...\}$ of multi-indices of degree $d$ in $n$ variables and consider the Hankel-type matrix $B=(b_{\alpha+\beta})$, whose $(\alpha,\beta)$th entry equals $b_{\alpha+\beta}$. Computer experiments for small $d$ and $n$ seem to suggest that the degree $2d$ form $\sum_{\alpha,\beta} (B^{-1})_{\alpha,\beta} x^{\alpha+\beta}$ is proportional to the $d$th power of the quadratic form $(x^{\,t} A x)^d$. We are convinced that this holds in general, but could not prove it. Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting. I think I can explain why the degree $2d$ form $\sum B_{\alpha,\beta} x^{\alpha+\beta}$ would be proportional to the $d$th power of the same quadratic form $(x^t A^{-1} x)^d$ that you started with. I don't know if you would be interested in hearing that (perhaps you already know that much). I'm not sure what to do about the inverses, though.

Comment: @ZachTeitler, thanks for your comment! I think these are not proportional... I agree it is tempting to believe that they are, but already for n=2 and d=2 it is not the case!